# The extra "2 q" in mysql.cnf

Tags: vim, mysql, configure

Show content in mysql.cnf file.

```
cat   /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
[mysql]
```

Show it with binary format.

```
xxd /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
00000000: 5b6d 7973 716c 5d0a                      [mysql].
```

Now open it with vim.
[image]

Why `2 q` shows here?

Comment: Binary format shows none symbols after `[mysql]<LF>`. So it is some vim issue... You may remove [mysql] and [configure] tags as non-relative.

Comment: Sounds like it's similar to [Nvim shows weird symbols (�[2 q) when changing modes](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#nvim-shows-weird-symbols-2-q-when-changing-modes) (also see https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/7049).

Comment: This usually happens, when your terminal pretends to be xterm compatible but really isn't. Vim has fixed this in one of its ealier 8 patches I believe, so consider updating your vim.